# Drawing stars in Image-Box

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image, drawing

I wanted to make a little test how to draw "stars" into a Imagebox called image1 in a WPF-C#-Application. There's a timer that when it elapses invokes the functions to create and draw the starset. The whole approach may be a little humble and since I'm really bad at mathematics it may seem a little abstruse to people who are better in it. The problem is that when I create a new starset, with new coordinates for new stars, it perfectly fine prints out a new image. (Commenting out the !starList.Any() clause in DrawTimer_Elapsed and the updateStars() invoke - so just left createStarSet() in), but when updateStars is executed the X and Y values for the stars seem to increase (as they should and with them I hope the drawing points) but the picture remains the same even if it should get updated by draw(). Hope it was at least little understandable

Thanks already

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Drawing;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DrawTimer.Interval = 100;
            DrawTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.DrawTimer_Elapsed);
            DrawTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        public System.Timers.Timer DrawTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        public Random rndGen = new Random();
        public bool drawable = true;

        public void DrawTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {          
            DrawTimer.Stop();
        if (!starList.Any())
        {
            image1.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => this.createStarSet()), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
        }
        else
        {
            image1.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => this.updateStars()), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
        }
            image1.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => this.draw()), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background); 
            DrawTimer.Start();
        }

        public void updateStars()
        {
            foreach (Star myStar in starList)
            {
                myStar._X += 1;
                myStar._Y += 1;
            }
        }

        private void canvas1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DrawTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        public List<Star> starList = new List<Star>();

        public const int MAX_STARS = 100;

        public void draw() 
        {
            drawable = false;
            GeometryGroup allMyStars = new GeometryGroup();
            foreach (Star myStar in starList)
            {
                allMyStars.Children.Add(new EllipseGeometry(new Point(myStar._X, myStar._Y), 2, 2));
            }
            GeometryDrawing drawing = new GeometryDrawing();
            drawing.Geometry = allMyStars;
            drawing.Pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 2);
            DrawingImage finishedImage = new DrawingImage();
            finishedImage.Drawing = drawing;
            image1.Source = finishedImage;
            image1.Stretch = Stretch.None;
            drawable = true;
        }

        public void createStarSet()
        {
            starList = new List<Star>();
            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_STARS; i++)
            {
                starList.Add(new Star(rndGen,this));
            }
        }

        public class Star 
        {
            public int _X = 0;
            public int _Y = 0;
            public double _Speed = 0.0f;
            public Star(Random rndGen, Window wdw)
            {
                _X = rndGen.Next(-(int)Math.Floor((wdw.Width / 8)), (int)Math.Floor((wdw.Width / 8)));
                _Y = rndGen.Next(-(int)Math.Floor((wdw.Height / 8)), (int)Math.Floor((wdw.Height / 8)));
                _Speed = rndGen.Next(1, 100) / 100;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Name="asca" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="399.875" Width="806" MouseMove="asca_MouseMove">
    <Image x:Name="image1" Margin="0"/>
</Window>
```

Comment: Can we see your XAML code please?

Comment: oh yes I will attach it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok..this one was a tricky one and has got me for about an hour. The problem with your code is that you are moving all the stars the same step all the time, so the "relative position" between them is the same. I've never worked with `GeometryGroup` and `GeometryDrawing`,but it seems that it automatically resizes the image and centers it all, so thats why it seems to you that nothing is moving.

I think that you have some options. One would be drawing your own bitmap, where you can set absolute positions for your stars (i think that would just work fine). Other may be using wpf Animations.

Anyway, your code works if you assign a diferent direction to each star, thus changing the relative position between them,something like:

**Star class**

```
public class Star 
    {
        public int _X = 0;
        public int _Y = 0;
        public double _Speed = 0.0f;
        public int _Direction;

        public Star(int x, int y, double speed)
        {
            _X = x;
            _Y = y;
            _Speed = speed;
        }

        public Star(Random rndGen, Window wdw)
        {
            _X = rndGen.Next(-(int)Math.Floor((wdw.Width / 8)), (int)Math.Floor((wdw.Width / 8)));
            _Y = rndGen.Next(-(int)Math.Floor((wdw.Height / 8)), (int)Math.Floor((wdw.Height / 8)));
            _Speed = rndGen.Next(1, 100) / 100;
            _Direction = rndGen.Next(0, 4);
        }
    }
```

**UpdateStars Method**

```
public void updateStars()
    {

        foreach (Star myStar in starList)
        {

            switch (myStar._Direction)
            {
                case 1:
                    myStar._X += 1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    myStar._Y += 1;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    myStar._X -= 1;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    myStar._Y -= 1;
                    break;
            }

        }

    }
```

You can see this way you really see the "stars" moving. Hope this helps

Comment: This was indeed helpful :) Makes sense, I didn't make any deeper lookup about how GeometryDrawing works internally. I try to figure out a solution and drop it here also. Thanks for your input.